# Как в Linux получить стандартное разрешение монитора?

Tags: c++, linux

Каким образом GPU получает дефолтное разрешение монитора? Как по HDMI запросить дефолтное разрешение монитора?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977169/178576)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Монитор сообщает свои параметры через EDID.

Посмотреть эту конфигурацию проще всего с интерфейса `sysfs` подсистемы `DRI`.

Указатель на первую видеокарту в папке /sys/class/drm/card0.
Там несколько папок с выходами видеокарты:

```
 card0-DP-1
 card0-eDP-1
 card0-HDMI-A-1
 card0-HDMI-A-2
```

Смотрим подключение

```
cat card0-eDP-1/status          
connected
```

И сама конфигурация. Она в бинарном виде. Как монитор отдал - так и лежит.

```
cat card0-eDP-1/edid | parse-edid

Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "��"
    ModelName "��"
    VendorName "CMN"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 38 of 2015
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 310 170
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 76.42 1366 1434 1479 1592 768 772 779 800 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

Интересующие параметры можно распарсить и самому. В примере парсер отсюда http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/

Comment: get-edid из того проекта у меня не заработал)

Comment: но и dri хорошо отдает